# How does NSString/NSMutableString terminate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring, termination

In Objective C, I have a `NSMutableString` and I am accessing its characters using `characterAtIndex:` method for some manipulation.

For this, I also have to check for the terminating character somewhat like this:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"hello"];
for(int i = 0; [str characterAtIndex:i] != '???'; i++) // ??? = terminator
     //do something
```

So, as the above code defines, I am confused about the **terminating character** that **NSString/NSMutableString** uses. Is it `\0` like in `char *` or something else?

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no terminator. You use the `length` method.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    unichar ch = [str characterAtIndex:i];
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked fine, but I am still confused as how the compiler will know for itself about which is the end. Lets say we have a string "abc", then how the compiler knows that 'c' is the last character. Does it also use the `length` of the string to determine it?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know. It's a runtime feature provided by the `NSString` class.